# Python Pandas - Converting data types of columns raises NotImplementedError

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a DataFrame object with 10 columns. 9 of those columns are of type object, 6 of which I'm trying to convert into type "category", since all of these columns contain a lot of duplicate values. Here's the piece of code for that:

```
for col in ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5', 'Col6']:
    df[col] = df[col].astype('category')
```

But this code raises the following exception:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\categorical.py", line 378, in __init__
raise NotImplementedError("> 1 ndim Categorical are not "
NotImplementedError: > 1 ndim Categorical are not supported at this time
```

What might be the reason for this error message?
I know, there are several questions similar to this one here, but those did not solve my problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: @jezrael 0.24.1

Comment: So how working `cols = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5', 'Col6']` and then `df[cols] = df[cols].astype('category')` ?

Comment: @jezrael Gives the same error message

Comment: @HidayetRzayev please check if you have lists as values within your columns?

Comment: @Francisco All of the values are strings, but some of those strings are enclosed in brackets, e.g. [some text]. Might that cause the problem?

Comment: @HidayetRzayev I'm assuming so. [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-do-i-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe) has a very good post on this.